# Android Studio — App not showing up/launching on Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, emulation

I am rather new to Android Studio and needed help as my app couldn't launch in the emulator despite following all the solutions I can find based on others' experiences.

I have 2 activities currently — Main and Login. I will post the AndroidManifest.xml below. Thank you all for the help and time in advanced!! (I also have this message in my event log: Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:host="ID.firebaseapp.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>



</application>
```

Comment: Main activity is not declared in the manifest and you need to provide main launcher intent filter too.

Comment: @UmangBurman Hi thanks for your reply! I have amended my code but haven't added any intent filter to my main activity as I wanted the login page to launch first (my main activity is currently empty now). But the app is still not showing up in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Try this below code:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="ID.firebaseapp.com"
            android:scheme="https" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Try it ... Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but its still not working. Will try and clean up my codes and see how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <data
                android:host="ID.firebaseapp.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" /> -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>



</application>
```

That maybe help you. :)

Comment: Thank you for the help, but its still not working. Will try and clean up my codes and see how it goes!